# Declaring a 2D coordinate in Perl / C / C++

Tags: perl

I am trying to declare a variable in perl that holds two values that is I want to declare a variable that acts like a 2D coordinate point.

Then I need to declare 'N' of these. That is I need to create N random points in a graph. I have to study percolation theory and have an algorithm in mind for this. But got stuck at this point.

Is it possible to do so in Perl? If yes, please provide the syntax for the same.

thanks

Comment: Please ask one question per programming language. If you are interested in knowing this for 3 different languages, ask 3 different questions. As it happens, this is done differently in all the 3 mentioned languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For C/C++, you can create a structure to hold a `x` and `y` value.

```
typedef struct {
    double x;
    double y;
} Coordinate;
```

Inside your main function, you can initialize it like that:

```
Coordinate treasure = {1.5, 3.2};
```

To modify a variable's value:

```
treasure.x = 3.0;
treasure.y = 4.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

**try to use structure in the c**

e.g

```
struct coOrdinator {
    double x;
    double y;

 };
```

Or

**if you want to use C++ use the class**

e.g.

```
 class coOrdinator {
    double x;
    double y;

 };
```

**And then define the array of the variables of structure or the class**

Comment: in C++ by default scope of member variable is  private ....so it is not same as the structure  with different name